# Разбить строку на массив строк с помощью регулярного выражения в C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, split

Есть строка:

```
string Value = "usual text1<tagID11111111>text without end tag<tagID22222222>formated text1<standarttag>usual text2<tagID33333333>formated text2<standarttag>usual text3";
```

Как с помощю регулярного выражения и `Regex.Split()` разбить эту строку на массив строк в виде:

```
[0] = usual text1
[1] = <tagID11111111>text without end tag
[2] = <tagID22222222>formated text1<standarttag>
[3] = usual text2
[4] = <tagID33333333>formated text2<standarttag>
[5] = usual text3
```

Comment: А почему не подходит Regex.Match? Split предполагает наличие разделителя...

Comment: @pavelip Мне абсолютно не важен способ достижения результата, так что подойдет любой способ, просто напишите выражение если знаете как это реализовать, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @SkyDancer: А покажите ваш _настоящий_ текст. Скорее всего, у вас один из стандартных форматов, а вы изобретаете велосипед. [Какая ваша _настоящая_ задача?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/10105)

Comment: @VladD: Это и есть настоящий формат, я изменил только названия тегов, а так, то это точная копия из исходника. Но мне ниже уже человек помог, так что уже не актуально в любом случае

Comment: @SkyDancer: Ну, это и значит ненастоящий. Например, если у вас по сути BBCode, то парсить его надо не так. Вообще, регулярки — очень неподходящий инструмент для синтаксического разбора, вы ещё намучаетесь с ними. Впрочем, ваша воля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, можно так попробовать:

```
var Value = "usual text1<tagID11111111>text without end tag<tagID22222222>formated text1<standarttag>usual text2<tagID33333333>formated text2<standarttag>usual text3";
var splits = Regex.Split(Value, @"((?:<tagID\d+>)?[^<]+(?:<standarttag>)?)");
foreach (var s in splits)
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

[Регулярное выражение](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=((%3F%3A%3CtagID%5Cd%2B%3E)%3F%5B%5E%3C%5D%2B(%3F%3A%3Cstandarttag%3E)%3F)&i=usual%20text1%3CtagID11111111%3Etext%20without%20end%20tag%3CtagID22222222%3Eformated%20text1%3Cstandarttag%3Eusual%20text2%3CtagID33333333%3Eformated%20text2%3Cstandarttag%3Eusual%20text3):

```
((?:<tagID\d+>)?[^<]+(?:<standarttag>)?)
```

Находит:

- `<tagID\d+>` - `<tagID{ЦИФРЫ}>`
- `[^<]+` - 1 и более символов отличных от `<`
- `<standarttag>` - `<standarttag>`.

Так как всё выражение заключено в круглые скобки, весь найденный текст добавляется в конечный массив. Так как в нём присутствуют пустые элементы, их надо удалить. Можно и с помощью LINQ:

```
var splits = Regex.Split(Value, @"((?:<tagID\d+>)?[^<]+(?:<standarttag>)?)")
                  .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p))
                  .ToList();
```

[Пример кода на IDEONE](http://ideone.com/sesG9Y)

Comment: Работает замечательно, огроменное спасибо! Но можно как ни будь еще дополнить условие что может быть `<tagID11111111>` а может быть просто без скобок `tagID11111111`, что бы находило два варианта?

Comment: А хотя не нужно, подправил чуть базу и все работает как нужно. Еще раз огромное спасибо.

Comment: На всякий случай: знак вопроса говорит о том, что предыдущий знак или группа являются необязательными: `<?tagID11111111>?` найдёт и *<tagID11111111>*, и *<tagID11111111*, и *tagID11111111>*, и *tagID11111111*.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.